# Compile codes with my own compiler in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction

Hi
Anybody knows how can I use VS2010 IDE to write my own language codes and compile it with my own compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not suggest to use .Net in any case to write your own programming language/compiler. If you use .net, then the person who will be using your compiler must have .net framework. And also the program will undergo lots of conversion from your launguage -> your compiler-> converted .net code -> .net stuffs here to generate the code for windows. It will just add one more step.

EDIT:

Here are some references of compilers, you can use them as your guide.

http://wiki.freepascal.org/Compiler_development_articles

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

Comment: The OP didn't say they were using .NET to write their language.

Comment: You are right, but using VS2010 as Editor is not a bad idea, then i can write my own editor seprately...

Comment: Yes you can use VS IDE for writing your own code. I think you will have to write a plugin and a project template for VS IDE so that you can create a project type with project template and plugin for syntax highlighting, syntax checking, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at IronPython, and specifically the [IronPython tools for Visual Studio](http://ironpython.net/tools/) which is OpenSourced and so you might be able to see how they do it.